# Spring Boot/Batch: Should every Job be separate Maven module?

Tags: java, design, architecture, spring, modularization

I'm building a backend service powered by Spring Batch which enables to define and `Job`s.

Currently, I have several jobs, that essentially, aren't related one to another.

So,

- I have one `application.properties` file that contains all the properties for all jobs
- Packages are bloated with classes that aren't related to each other.

So I thought about separating Jobs to different Maven modules and to have an `engine` module that gathers them all to one jar.

The problem I was facing is that Spring wouldn't load automatically these `application.properties` from the other modules.

i.e. `$Value("${some.module.property}")` will fail the application (`engine.jar`) as this property isn't found in the `application.properties` of the `engine` module.

I've understood that there might be some solutions for that problem, but my main question is:

**Is it a good idea to make this separation, or is it bearable to have all the classes and configurations in one single project?**

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. The question are `what are your outcome` ? `What do you want to achieve?`

Here you talk about going to a `modular monolith`. It could be the last step before going to a microservice deployment approach (each job is completely independent.. build, deploy and run separately).

To respond to your question: sounds a good solution if for instance :

- you want to assign different owner by module(aka developer) and push forward `Team/Job autonomy`..
- decrease the build time, code-quality review time(like sonar review) that take too long when apply to a global package.
- Improve cohesion and decrease risk of coupling that could appear by sharing some code between job implementations

Another question could be `why these jobs are packaged together if they aren't chained?`

Maybe they could be completely split and going with each job having their own lifecyle and being independently deployable and runnable --> `so one fat-jar by job`